# Reading Environment specific variables from test file Compound.js

Tags: node.js, testing, environment-variables, mocha.js, compoundjs

I'm working on a compound js app. In environments/test.js I have exported a variable as follows:

```
app.host = "http://mysite.com"
```

When I run the app as below:

```
NODE_ENV=test node .
```

I could access the value of host by giving app.host. Everything is fine till here.

I'm using mocha for testing. When I try to access app.host from my test file, I'm getting an error saying,

```
ReferenceError: app is not defined.
```

Any idea on how to access the variables from environment/test.js file from test/*.js files would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u post one of your mocha tests where the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

**environments/test.js**

```
module.exports = {
  host: "http://example.com"
};
```

**app.js**

```
var app;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  app = require("./environments/test.js");
}

console.log(app.host);
```

If you load the module at the top of the Mocha test it should be OK.